# recognizing an audio file

Tags: android

I added an audio file to my project in the raw folder in res directory.
But Android Studio doesn't recognize its file type.

What should I do?
See my directory

[image]

Comment: it is not important, you do your job with that audio file, android will support that

Comment: @HamidReza Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting... Some music notes on the OGG file icon?

Don't worry about it. You can still use `R.raw.Signs_of_Life` in your app